# Convert association to Matrix / List

Tags: list-manipulation

I am completely new to Mathematica.

I have an association in the form
`<| a -> {1,2,3,4},b -> {5,4,3,2},c -> {5,7,3,4} |>`

I want my output to be of the form 
`{{a,1,2,3,4},{b,5,4,3,2},{c,5,7,3,4}}`

Can I do that?
I have tried different things but could not figure out any thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
asso = <| a -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, b -> {5, 4, 3, 2}, c -> {5, 7, 3, 4} |>;

KeyValueMap[Flatten[{##}] &] @ asso
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {c, 5, 7, 3, 4}}

Also

```
Flatten /@ List @@@ Normal @ asso
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {c, 5, 7, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

You can combine matrices column-wise with `Join[mat1, mat2, 2]`

```
asso = <|a -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, b -> {5, 4, 3, 2}, c -> {5, 7, 3, 4}|>;
Join[Transpose[{Keys[asso]}], Values[asso], 2]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {c, 5, 7, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyValueMap[Join[{#1}, #2] &, ass]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {c, 5, 7, 3, 4}}